# Unable to Call Subroutine

Tags: excel, excel-2010, subroutine, vba

I am unable to call sub BCD if user input valid week number in userform. If user input invalid or empty week number, sub BCD will execute.

What wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub cmdOK1_Click()

Call ABC
Call BCD

End Sub

Sub ABC()

'Prompt message box when week number is empty
    If Me.txtWeekNo.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter week number to print.", vbExclamation, "Print Work Order by Schedule"
        Me.txtWeekNo.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Check for valid week number
LColumn = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(5, Worksheets("RIG PMS").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Define last column in week number
Set WeekNoRng = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Range(Cells(5, 10), Cells(5, LColumn))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WeekNoRng, txtWeekNo.Value) = 0 Then
         MsgBox "Invalid Week Number"
         Exit Sub
        Else
            Unload UserForm1
    End If

    'Determine Column
        For i = 10 To LColumn
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(5, i), txtWeekNo.Value) > 0 Then
                Acolumn = i
            End If
        Next i

LRow = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Set OpenWORng = Worksheets("Open WO").Range("B3:B" & Worksheets("Open WO").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For a = 7 To LRow Step 3
        AA = 0
        If Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn).Value <> "" And Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn - 2).Value = 1 Then
            b = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, 7).Value
            Worksheets("Power Pack Monthly").Range("C5").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a - b, 2).Value 'Asset Code
            Worksheets("Power Pack Monthly").Range("C6").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a - b, 3).Value 'Description
            Worksheets("Power Pack Monthly").Range("P5").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn).Value 'WO
            Worksheets("Power Pack Monthly").Range("P6").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a + 1, Acolumn).Value 'Proposed Date
            AA = 1
        End If

        If Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn).Value <> "" And Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn - 2).Value = 2 Then
            b = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, 7).Value
            Worksheets("Power Pack 6 Monthly").Range("C5").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a - b, 2).Value 'Asset Code
            Worksheets("Power Pack 6 Monthly").Range("C6").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a - b, 3).Value 'Description
            Worksheets("Power Pack 6 Monthly").Range("P5").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn).Value 'WO
            Worksheets("Power Pack 6 Monthly").Range("P6").Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a + 1, Acolumn).Value 'Proposed Date
            AA = 1
        End If

    'Copy Open WO to Open WO Sheet
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(OpenWORng, Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn).Value) = 0 And AA = 1 Then
            Worksheets("Open WO").Range("B" & Worksheets("Open WO").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a, Acolumn).Value 'WO No.
            Worksheets("Open WO").Range("C" & Worksheets("Open WO").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a - b, 2).Value 'Asset Code
            Worksheets("Open WO").Range("D" & Worksheets("Open WO").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Worksheets("RIG PMS").Cells(a - b, 3).Value 'Asset Description
            Worksheets("Open WO").Range("E" & Worksheets("Open WO").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = 1 'For trigger purpose
        End If

        If a = LRow - 2 Then
            MsgBox "Continue"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next a

End Sub

Sub BCD()

   MsgBox "ABC"

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code should be in the command button

Comment: call BCD will be insert of the bottom of the sub ABC, then It play only when all condition in the sub BCD was confirmed

Comment: Fabrizio, i did insert call BCD at the bottom of sub ABC but it still not worked

Comment: I haven't your file then I can't test it, but is logical if you have insert BCD in the bottom of sub ABC, and you has deleted the call BCD on cmdOK1_Click(), the sub BCD run only if the conditions that you have check will be true.

Comment: @cklim have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

**Error reproduction:** I was able to reproduce the behavior mentioned in the question by having all procedures posted located in the `CodeModule` of the `UserForm`.

**Reason for the behavior:** The second procedure `BCD` is not running when the week number is valid because the `UserFrom` is unloaded as per this line:

```
Unload UserForm1
```

The remarks at [Unload Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251690(v=office.15).aspx) says:

> **Remarks:** When an object is unloaded, it's removed from memory and all
>   memory associated with the object is reclaimed. Until it is placed in
>   memory again using the Load statement, a user can't interact with an
>   object, and the object can't be manipulated programmatically.

**Solution:** Although several solutions apply, in my opinion the easiest is to move procedure `BCD` to a standard module - *tested*.

**Other Solutions:**

- Move both procedures out of the `UserForm` but the all references to objects in the `UserForm` have to be qualified (i.e. replace `Me` with `UserForm1` and references to `TxtWeekNo` have to be qualified as `UserForm1.TxtWeekNo`) - *tested*.
- Hide the user form instead and unload it at the end of the `cmdOK1_Click` procedure.
- and probably many others.

Answer (score -3):

The code is in the class module for the form. It should be in a standard module.

Comment: shg and Davesexcel : no i doesn't need to be in the command button code, nor in a separate module. You can call it from anywhere in the same workbook (if not a private sub). By the way, you say "my code was unable to call sub BCD" , meaning error message, infinite loop, code Stop ,.... ?? My advice , add a simple break point to ABC and debug it step by step (F8 key)...

Comment: Patrick, no error pop up when execute this code. I used F8 for step by step debug. It work for Sub ABC as per expected. MsgBox "Continue" did pop up as well then it jump back to Private Sub cmdOK1_Click() and step into Sub Call in Private Sub then directly go to End Sub instead of jump to Sub BCD to pop up MsgBox "ABC"